# Unable to connect Firebase in Android Emulator for Flutter Project

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to connect signin into my app, i am getting this error

```
W/System  (14618): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/flutter (14618): Login Error:: [firebase_auth/unknown] com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Chain validation failed ]
```

Last week  i dint have any issue in sign in, i have no idea y i got this suddenly , i even changed the google-services.json file.

Can anyone help on this issue, i don’t have any issue while connecting in real device(android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check you internet connection, Firebase needs stable connection and rebuild the project again. if this is not working, share some code.

Comment: Thanks for you response. Internet connection is working fine, I am connecting the IOS simulator its working fine. I dont have any issue in connecting to my real android device. Its not working only in the Emulator.

Comment: Yes, it was internet connectivity, now its fixed. Thank You 

Comment: @Elam what specifically was wrong with your internet connection? My iOS emulator and physical android device works fine but the Android emulator doesn't. My android emulator can connect to the internet and APIs but Firebase isn't working. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have installed wrong Android emulator for my Apple M1. After i installed the correct emulator it worked. Because of this issue my app dint connect to internet .  What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I had to wipe the data from my android emulator to get it working again without network errors. It remain successful with my iOS emulator (on an M2)